# How to input hyphen as many as the number of characters in the line above?

Tags: vim, restructuredtext

I want to input specific character as many as the number of characters in the line above.

Before:

```
FooBar
```

After:

```
FooBar
------
```

I want to use this function to write reStructuredText

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
yypVr-
```

Yank the line, paste it, then change every character to a dash.

Comment: You can also set a macro like this `:let @a="yypVr-"` then you cant call the macro `a` with `@a` and after the first run you can repeat the last macro by hitting `@@`.